# Calculate sum using eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, laravel-5

I was wondering how to calculate revenues using eloquent ORM.

**The challenge:**
Calculate the planned revenue for each clients. Each clients has many projects.

**Question:**
How can I make operations such as "budget-cost" outside SQL. Can i put this into my model or somewhere else to access these "special" attributes in my view?

This code is working, but not very elegant, I guess.

```
    $planned_clients = DB::table('clients')
        ->join('projects', 'clients.id', '=', 'projects.client_id')
        ->select('projects.*', 'clients.title as client_title',
            DB::raw('SUM(projects.planned_budget) as planned_budget'),
            DB::raw('SUM(projects.planned_costs) as planned_costs'),
            DB::raw('SUM(projects.planned_budget) - SUM(projects.planned_costs) as total_revenue')
        )
        ->where('projects.commitment', '=', Project::PLANNED)
        ->whereNotIn('projects.status', [Project::CANCELED])
        ->groupBy('projects.client_id')
        ->get();
```

Here are the schemas

```
class CreateClientsTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('client_id')->unique();
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->boolean('is_keyclient')->default(0);
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}


class CreateProjectsTable extends Migration {

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('project_id')->unique();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
            $table->enum('commitment', array('save', 'planned'));
            $table->enum('status', array('waiting', 'running', 'done', 'canceled', 'cleared'));
            $table->string('comment');
            $table->integer('planned_budget');
            $table->integer('planned_costs');
            $table->integer('actual_budget');
            $table->integer('actual_costs');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


        Schema::table('projects', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the DB structure, such as relations and column names of both tables?

Comment: of course. see last edit.